# How to set default createdBy and editedBy in Grails audit-trail plugin from Bootstrap?

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.2.2, audit-trail plugin 2.0.3, and spring-security-core 1.2.7.3

When I put the annotation on a class and insert record using browser (through Controller/gsp), everything works fine.

```
@gorm.AuditStamp
class Note {
   String name
}
```

However, when I insert record within Bootstrap

```
new Note(name:'Testing').save()
```

I get error on startup

```
ERROR property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - IllegalArgumentException in class: test.Note, setter method of property: createdBy
ERROR property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.lang.Integer
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of test.Note.createdBy; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of test.Note.createdBy
```

Is there a way to fix to make audit-trail work during Bootstrap?  I just with to place default value when inserted from Bootstrap, and the logged user when inserted using browser screen.  I use the following changes but still no luck:

```
static mapping = {
    createdBy (defaultValue: Long.valueOf( 1l ))
    editedBy (defaultValue: Long.valueOf( 1l ))
}
static constraints = {
    createdBy nullable:true
    editedBy nullable:true
}
```

I still get the same Long/Integer error

Edit:

This is the content of my Config.groovy that is related to this pkugin

```
grails {
    plugin{
        audittrail{
            createdBy.field = "createdBy"
            editedBy.field = "editedBy"
            createdDate.field = "createdDate"
            editedDate.field = "editedDate"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the setup you have done in `Config.groovy` for those fields if you have any? And the latest version of the plugin is see is 2.0.0, have you cloned the plugin from the repo?

Comment: @dmahapatro it's one of the (many) cases where the plugin portal metadata is out of sync with the [repository](http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/audit-trail/), which does have 2.0.3

Comment: @dmahapatro i edited and put the config related to audittrail.  I just installed using command line and let grails choose the correct version for me.

Comment: "I just installed using command line" - note that `grails install-plugin` is deprecated and the correct way to install plugins since Grails 1.3 is to put a dependency in `BuildConfig` instead.

Comment: thanks Ian. I didn't know that.  I just use install plugin and its registered in application.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth` to fake a security context

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

// set up a default user, if one doesn't already exist
def defaultUser = User.findByUsername('default') ?: new User(username:'default').save()

// run the following code as if that user were logged in
SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth('default') {
  new Note(name:'Testing').save()
}
```

Comment: it worked.  it's just weird intellij can't detech the SpringSecurityUtils class.  I just searched the package on the net

Comment: @JavaDev It's provided by the `spring-security-core` Grails plugin.

Comment: yes it is there. it is just intellij cant see the class. thanks for the help!